# Error calling soap web service with certificate

Tags: wcf, soap, .net-6.0

I am trying to make a call to a soap webservice however I am getting a error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This error is thrown when calling `tsk.Result;` Which ends up calling `protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` which is in the class below. at which point it errors on `return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);`

```
    public void CallService()
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                        CardholderManagementServicePortTypeClient client = new CardholderManagementServicePortTypeClient();
                        client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://uat.thirdpartyservice.com/ourservice/");
                        
                        client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CorrelationEndpointBehavior());
                        client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.Root, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "Thirdpartycert");
                        RequestSecurityType t = new RequestSecurityType();
                        t.userId = "1";
                        
        
                        FindCardRequestType req = new FindCardRequestType();
                        req.servicingCentre = "902223";
        
                        var tsk= client.findCardAsync(t, req);
                        var res=tsk.Result;
    }

public class CustomCorrelationDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
        {
            public CustomCorrelationDelegatingHandler(HttpClientHandler handler)
            {
                InnerHandler = handler;
            }

            protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                request.Headers.Add("userNameToken", "0R9DDOwTRUERh0UY623Q2bPNv8M=");
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        public class CorrelationEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
        {
            public CorrelationEndpointBehavior()
            {
            }

            public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
            {
                bindingParameters.Add(new Func<HttpClientHandler, HttpMessageHandler>(x =>
                {
                    //x.ClientCertificates.Add()
                    return new CustomCorrelationDelegatingHandler(x);
                }));
            }

            public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime) { }
            public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }
            public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }
        }
```

I was getting an error referring to not being able to access the private key. But I solved this with the following article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-make-x-509-certificates-accessible-to-wcf

I have no idea what is causing the error as it is happening inside .net libraries...

If I replace

```
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.Root, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "Thirdpartycert");
```

with

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\me\Postman\files\Cert.pfx", "travel1");
                client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;
```

I get the same error.

If it is not clear why this is happening in my code, I am happy to copy an example of someones working code...

Basically I simply need the code to connect with a certificate and include a token in the header...

I have noticed in some examples they also add a servicecertificate. What is the difference between that and the client certificate and how do I know which one I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Which certificate to use depends on whether you are writing a client or a service.[Which Certificate to Use?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/working-with-certificates#which-certificate-to-use)
The client certificate is used to authenticate the client's identity to the server, while the server certificate authenticates the server's identity to the client.
https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/what-is-the-difference-between-client-and-server-certificates 
https://www.clickssl.net/blog/server-certificate-vs-client-certificate

**Client Certificate vs Server Certificate** 
[image]